# Voting to close versus unilaterally closing

Tags: discussion

Usually when I click to close a question, it's just a vote.  But sometimes the question is closed immediately just on my say-so.  I haven't been able to discern the pattern.

**Why is it sometimes just a vote to close and sometimes an instant decision?**

(I understand that the instant decision never happened until I hit some rep threshold.  But now that I'm above the threshold, it seems unpredictable.)

I find the unpredictability of it disconcerting.  There are times where I hope it's just a vote because I'm only 75% sure, and then I end up closing a question immediately, and then I feel guilty because maybe I single-handedly closed a question that didn't deserve to be closed.  I find I'm getting very conservative about clicking close at all, ever.

If it's just me, then it's probably not a big deal.  But if many others who've crossed the rep threshold of unpredictably unilateral closing power are also getting conservative with their close actions, then that's probably not good for the site overall.

Comment: You have a c++ gold badge and can close questions marked with the c++ tag as duplicates single handedly. Carry that power with care. You can also reopen those duplicates single handedly BTW.

Comment: Thanks!   That completely explains why I was never able to predict the outcome.